# Windows 10 upgrade if older Windows is not installed

Tags: windows-7, windows-10-upgrade

I have a laptop that was shipped with Windows 7. For some reason, the PC was always extremely slow with Windows 7, so on one day of frustration I took a spare drive and installed Ubunto into it. However, even though the performance was great, we kind of missed having Windows on that PC (full MS-Office compatibility, Amazon Prime Video in HD, among other details that only work on Windows).

When I heard about the free upgrade to Windows 10, I decided to delete the Ubuntu drive and install the Insider Preview. The laptop now runs quite smoothly, better as new. However, I am wondering how the upgrade process would be in this case:

- I could install the old drive and click the icon after running all the upgrades, but I have no interest on upgrading to Win10 over the old Win7 installation, it is just too full of HP-Bloatware, I want a clean install.
- Is or will there be any way to get a Win10 key using the product key from Windows 7?

Comment: Do you mean to ask with your first bullet point *How can I take advantage of the Windows 10 upgrade but **perform a clean install** of Windows 10*? If so, please edit accordingly

Answer (score -3):

As you are running the Insider Preview, as long as you keep installing the next couple of builds until July 29th, you will get the full-license, even if you don't have an older version of windows installed.

> Windows Insiders running the Windows 10 Insider Preview (Home and Pro editions) with their registered MSA connected to their PC will receive the final release build of Windows 10 starting on July 29th.

It is also worth noting that after you update to the final release version on/after July 29th, you will be able to clean-install Windows 10 on that PC.

> As long as you are running an Insider Preview build and connected with the MSA you used to register, you will receive the Windows 10 final release build. Once you have successfully installed this build, you will also be able to clean install on that PC from final media if you want to start over fresh.

[Source](http://blogs.windows.com/bloggingwindows/2015/06/19/upcoming-changes-to-windows-10-insider-preview-builds/)

Comment: They later retracted that statement.  User of the Insider Preview will be able to upgrade to the RTM build but they are not going to get a FREE license despite any news to the saying otherwise. **The only exception is if you upgrade the WIndows 7 installation to the Insider Preview.**

Comment: So being able to use Windows 10 RTM is different in what way from having a license? Gabe said that you don't need to upgrade the installation to receive an activated Windows 10 after July 29th  - https://twitter.com/GabeAul/status/612674365436526592

Comment: The blog post has been [updated](https://www.neowin.net/images/uploaded/2015/06/screen_shot_2015-06-21_at_2.04.18_pm.jpg) find a more recent link

Comment: So people understand what Gabe Aul actually means.  They are going to continue to send out test builds to the Insider Preview members.  If you have the Insider Preview build installed, eventually you will recieve the RTM build, and every build after that.  They are basically going to continue the Insider Preview forever.  Which also means certain build eventually most then likely expire .  Microsoft is not giving away FREE licenses to people not already running Windows 7 or Windows 8.1.  It will be activaed but it will be a technical preview license not a retail/oem license.